# Keep the figure size at full scale for multiple figures

Tags: r, shiny, figure

The following code allows to have multiple user-defined graphs using `patchwork` library. However, as the number of figures increases, the size becomes smaller. is there any way to keep the size of each figure at predefined heights and width or keep the total height at 100%?

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)
library(patchwork)

plt_func <- function(x,y){
  plt_list <- list()
  for (X_var in x){
    plt_list[[X_var]] <- mtcars %>% ggplot(aes_string(X_var, y))+
      geom_point() + 
      labs(x = X_var, y = y)
  }
  
  if (length(plt_list) == 1) {
    return(plt_list[[1]])
  } else {
    patchwork::wrap_plots(plt_list, ncol = min(length(plt_list), 2)) %>% print(.)
  }
}


ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel( 
      selectInput(inputId = "dataset",
                  label = "Choose a dataset:",
                  choices = c("mtcars")),
      selectizeInput(inputId = "x",label = "X", choices = names(mtcars), multiple = T),
      selectInput(inputId = "y",label = "Y", choices = names(mtcars),multiple = F),
      selectInput(inputId = "t",label = "Treatment", choices = names(mtcars),multiple = F),
                 actionButton("plot", label = "Plot")),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("plots")
      
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  observeEvent(input$plot, {
    req(input$x, input$y)
    x <- input$x
    y <- input$y
    
    output$plots <- renderPlot({
        
        plt_func(x,y)
    
    
    })
  
    
})
  

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

figure size when there are two figures:

[image]

figure size when there are 6 figures:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default height is `400px`. You can change it with the `height` argument of `renderPlot`:

```r
  observeEvent(input$plot, {
    req(input$x, input$y)
    x <- input$x
    y <- input$y
    nplots <- (length(x) + 1L) %/% 2L
    
    output$plots <- renderPlot({
      plt_func(x,y)
    }, height = nplots * 400)
    
  })
```

***But*** it is not recommended to define an output slot inside an observer. It's better to do like this:

```r
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output[["plots"]] <- renderPlot({
    req(input$x, input$y)
    x <- input$x
    y <- input$y
    plt_func(x,y)
  }, height = exprToFunction(400 * ((length(input[["x"]]) + 1L) %/% 2L)) %>%
    bindEvent(input[["plot"]])
  
}
```

We need `exprToFunction` because `input[["x"]]` is a reactive variable.

Comment: Thank you, Stephane. 1- I think we need to wrape "nplots <- length(x) %/% 2L" in an "if statement" to make it work even when the user select only one variable and then such a case when length(x) == 1 then nplots  <- 1

Comment: 2- Why it's not recommended to put an output slot inside an observer?

Comment: @Abbas 1/ Ah yes you're right. 2/ I don't know, maybe for a memory consumption reason. The slot is recreated each time the inputs change if you put it in an observer. This is unnecessary.

Comment: The input changes only when the plot botton is pressed (event). hence called observeEvent()

Comment: @Abbas This is equivalent to the `bindEvent` I included in my code.

Comment: @Abbas The correct code is `nplots <- (length(x) + 1L) %/% 2L`. I edit to correct that.